# Bitcoin unconfirmed transaction help me please

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions

Been over 24 hours unconfirmed Transaction please help !!!
13fsWbUWdAPY9BajN7oiMerJSvw66eSYi2  It never takes this long

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The bitcoin network is overloaded. You must wait 1-3 days before your transaction will go through. There is nothing you can do now but wait.

Next time, you may send transactions with a higher fee so a miner gives it more priority.

Don't spend any money on a site that claims they can speed up your transaction. They are scams.